# Mixing Vertical and Horizontal layouts (for horizontally laid out class diagram)

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to display a class diagram in GraphViz.  I would like it to be laid out primarily horizontally - but am having a problem because it is separating out the three parts of each class horizontally too (i.e. class name, attributes, and methods) are also being displayed horizontally.  I have tried subgraphs with rankdir = LR for each individual node, but it isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
digraph hierarchy {
node[shape=record,style=filled,fillcolor=gray95]
edge[dir=back, arrowtail=empty]
graph[size="20,10"]
rankdir=LR

1[label = "{Hazards|+ ID\n + Description\n + RiskLevel|+f Topics}" ]
2[label = "{Faults|+ ID\n + Fault\n + Likelihood\n + Impact\n + Mitigation|+f Topics}"]
3[label = "{User Requirements|+ ID\n + Requirement\n + Status\n +     Priority\n + Contributors|+f NFR Types\n+fTopics\n +f Find-the-expert\n+f Volatility}"]
4[label = "{Acceptance Tests|+ TestID\n + Script\n +CurrentStatus|+f Coverage}"]
5[label = "{Acceptance Test Log|+ TestID\n +DateRun\n + Relevance}"]
6[label = "{Regulatory Codes|+ ID\n + Regulation\n + Likelihood\n + Impact\n + Mitigation|+f Topics}"]
7[label = "{State Transition Diagram|+ ID\n + States\n + Transitions\n + Model}"]
8[label = "{System Requirements|+ ID\n + Description\n +Status\n + Priority|+f Topics}"]
9[label = "{Work Item|+ ID\n +Description\n + AssignedTo\n + DateCompleted\n + Comments|+f ProjectVelocity}"]
10[label = "{Bug Tracker|+ ID\n + Title\n +ReportedOn\n + FixedOn\n + Symptoms\n + State\n + Effort|+f Find-the-expert}"]
11[label = "{Source Code|+ ClassName\n +Code\n + CreatedBy\n + CreatedOn\n + LastModifiedBy\n + LastModifiedOn|+f Fault Likelihood\n + f Topics}"]
12[label = "{Unit Tests|+ TestID\n + Script\n +CurrentStatus|+f Coverage}"]
13[label = "{Unit Test Log|+ TestID\n + DateRun\n + ByWhom\n +Status\n + ActionItems}"]
14[label = "{Components|+ ID\n + Name|+f  Fault Likelihood}"]

1->2
2->3
3->4
4->5
2->8
3->8
8->6
8->7
8->9
10->9
8->11
14->11
11->12
12->13
11->9
}
```

Unfortunately I am not allowed to post images as I don't have an StackOverflow reputation.  However, you can see the vertical solution by replacing rankdir =LR with rankdir=TB.

Does anyone know how to combine the two layouts so that the classes stay stacked i.e. class name above attributes above functions etc, but that the overall layout is LR?

I prefer not to use the UMLGraph.lib if there is a way to specify this directly in GraphVis.

Many thanks
jane

Comment: I am going to answer my own question - as I've been trying to solve this over the past few days.  It turns out that I just needed to omit the {} at the beginning and end of defining the text in the labels.  

So now a single label looks like this:
    1[label = "Hazards|+ ID\n + Description\n + RiskLevel\n+f Topics"]

This gives me exactly what I want.  A schema (similar to a class diagram) laid out left-to-right, with the three parts of the 'class' stacked vertically.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is therefore:

```
digraph hierarchy {
node[shape=record,style=filled,fillcolor=gray95]
edge[dir=back, arrowtail=empty]
graph[size="15,20"]
rankdir=LR

1[label = "Hazards|+ ID\n + Description\n + RiskLevel\n+f Topics"]
2[label = "Faults|+ ID\n + Fault\n + Likelihood\n + Impact\n + Mitigation|+f Topics"]
3[label = "User Requirements|+ ID\n + Requirement\n + Status\n + Priority\n + Contributors|+f NFR Types\n+fTopics\n +f Find-the-expert\n+f Volatility"]
4[label = "Acceptance Tests|+ TestID\n + Script\n +CurrentStatus|+f Coverage"]
5[label = "Acceptance Test Log|+ TestID\n +DateRun\n + Relevance"]
6[label = "Regulatory Codes|+ ID\n + Regulation\n + Likelihood\n + Impact\n + Mitigation|+f Topics"]
7[label = "State Transition Diagram|+ ID\n + States\n + Transitions\n + Model"]
8[label = "System Requirements|+ ID\n + Description\n +Status\n + Priority|+f Topics"]
9[label = "Work Item|+ ID\n +Description\n + AssignedTo\n + DateCompleted\n + Comments|+f ProjectVelocity"]
10[label = "Bug Tracker|+ ID\n + Title\n +ReportedOn\n + FixedOn\n + Symptoms\n + State\n + Effort|+f Find-the-expert"]
11[label = "Source Code|+ ClassName\n +Code\n + CreatedBy\n + CreatedOn\n + LastModifiedBy\n + LastModifiedOn|+f Fault Likelihood\n + f Topics"]
12[label = "Unit Tests|+ TestID\n + Script\n +CurrentStatus|+f Coverage"]
13[label = "Unit Test Log|+ TestID\n + DateRun\n + ByWhom\n +Status\n + ActionItems"]
14[label = "Components|+ ID\n + Name|+f  Fault Likelihood"]

1->2
2->3
3->4
4->5
2->8
3->8
8->6
8->7
8->9
10->9
8->11
14->11
11->12
12->13
11->9
```

}